# Keydown/keyup events not detecting the Escape key being pressed on input text fields in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jquery-events

I want to do something when the <kbd>escape</kbd> key is pressed by the user on a text field. [This code](http://jsfiddle.net/ghUey/) logs `27` whenever the <kbd>escape</kbd> key is pressed in the input box in Safari and Firefox, but not in Chrome. I also tried binding to `keyup`, not using jQuery (i.e., just using raw JavaScript), and tried using `keyCode` instead of `which`, none of which helped. Incidentally, Chrome seems to do just fine with all other keys like <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the modifier keys, etc. Any idea what's up?

NB: I'm using Chrome 22.0.1229.94 on Mountain Lion.

UPDATE: By the way, if it helps, when I press <kbd>escape</kbd> on the input box in Chrome, it loses focus while on the other two browsers it does not.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and your fiddle logs `27` for me every time I press Esc.

Comment: Which version/OS are you using?

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Hmm, that's weird. It doesn't work for me in Chrome 22.0.1229.94 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Maybe your escape key is broken

Comment: This works in 22.0.1229.94 on Windows 7. :D

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Finally found what was causing this: the [Vimium](https://github.com/philc/vimium) chrome extension, which catches the Escape key.

A bug has been filed for it here: https://github.com/philc/vimium/issues/499.

Comment: Haha, thank you! You have no idea how much time I spent on this, or how much it bugged me.

Comment: Vimium now provides a "passNextKey" command, so you can press <C-]><Esc> to send an <Esc> key to the input field.

Comment: How to set the `passNextKey`: [Using the Escape key in inputs](https://github.com/philc/vimium/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks#using-the-escape-key-in-inputs)